# Liquibase updating mysql db with junk values

Tags: mysql, liquibase

My Liquibase update changeset is given as below:

```
<changeSet author="liquibase" id="6226">
    <update tableName="master">
    <column name="insighttype" valueNumeric="0"/>
    <where>id=1</where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

While running liquibase command, in the log I see:

```
UPDATE db.master SET insighttype = 0 WHERE id=7
```

But when I go back and check in the database:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+
| id | insightname     | insighttype |
+----+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 | action_items    |             |
|  2 | sentiments      |             |
|  3 | wordcloud       |             |
|  4 | entity          |            |
|  5 | summary         |             |
|  6 | trade_info      |             |
|  7 | topic_modelling |            |
+----+-----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: What data type `insighttype` is?

Comment: `BOOLEAN` and I am using MySQL 5.6

Comment: This question help me resolve my issue where I had different update script per different schema. And update was not hardcoded value, but had method REPLACE call inside it. Instead of using _value_, _valueNumberic_ done a job for me.
This is my script if anybody has the same problem:  
`<changeSet id="id" author="me"> <update schemaName="schema1" tableName="TBL"> <column name="col" valueNumeric="REPLACE (col, 'DT', 'NX')"/> </update></changeSet>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update `boolean` columns, you should use `valueBoolean` attribute.

E.G.

```
<changeSet author="liquibase" id="6226">
    <update tableName="master">
        <column name="insighttype" valueBoolean="false"/>
        <where>id=1</where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```